# Average every item of multiple array (diffrent array length and the same array name)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

### Our array

This is the dynamic array,every data array have different number of elements.
how can i find index based average and then add final result to last index of the series array.

```
series[
{data:[1,2,3,5,10]},
{data:[6,9,10,6,10,6,5]},
{data:[2,5,4]},
]
```

### Our try :

```
    var data = []; 
    var sum = 0;
var newseries = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
                                    for(var j= 0;j<(Math.max(series[i].data.length);j++){
                                        var rmv_undified=series[i].data[j];
                                        if(rmv_undified!=undefined){
                                            sum+=parseFloat(rmv_undified)/series.length;
                                        }
                                    }
                                        data.push(sum);
                                    };
newseries.data = data;
series.push(newseries);
```

but i got result like this :

```
 series[
        {data:[1,2,3,5,10]},
        {data:[6,9,10,6,10,6,5]},
        {data:[2,5,4]},
        {data:[7,17.33,3.66]}
// wrong result of above code working 1+2+3+5+10/3 = 7,6+9+10+6+10+6+5/3 = 17.33,2+5+4/3 = 3.66
        ]
```

I need result :

```
series[
        {data:[1,2,3,5,10]},
        {data:[6,9,10,6,10,6,5]},
        {data:[2,5,4]},
        {data:[3,5.33,5.66,3.66,6.66,2,1.66]} // index based average

        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the max length of all arrays first, then iterate through series and average nth item each iteration until n is max length.

```js
let series = [
  {data:[1,2,3,5,10]},
  {data:[6,9,10,6,10,6,5]},
  {data:[2,5,4]},
];

const maxl = [].reduce.call(series, (max, obj) => Math.max(obj.data.length,  max), -1)

let avgs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < maxl; i++) {
  let avg = [].reduce.call(series, (acc, n) => acc + (n.data[i] ? n.data[i] : 0), 0)/series.length;
  avgs.push(avg);
}
series.push({data: avgs});
console.log(series);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution. We have to iterate first through `series` array and then through each `data` array.

```js
var series = [
  {data:[1,2,3,5,10]},
  {data:[6,9,10,6,10,6,5]},
  {data:[2,5,4]},
];

var averageArray=[];

series.forEach(function(obj){
  var sum=0;
  obj.data.forEach(function(arrValue){
    sum = sum + arrValue;
  });
  averageArray.push(sum/obj.data.length);
});

series.push({data:averageArray});
console.log(series)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over j first, and for fixed j iterate over the different arrays in series.

Alternatively you can keep your code and change
    `sum+=` 
to 
    `sum[j]+=` and initialize this variable as an array. Then you have to push accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the max length of the data array.  Then iterate through each item of the series array to find the average.  [punkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/jVqgDAtJnAN2mml0hUGX?p=preview)

```
function avgMultipleArrary(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  var sum = 0;
  var maxLen=arr[0].data.length;
  var resultArray = [];
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    arr.map(function(arrEle,index){
      if (maxLen < arrEle.data.length) {
        maxLen = arrEle.data.length;
      }
    })
   }

  for(var i=0;i<maxLen;i++){
    arr.map(function(arrEle,index){
      var data = arrEle.data;
        if(data[i] !== undefined)
          sum +=data[i];
    })
    var avg = Number((sum/len).toFixed(2));
    resultArray.push(avg)
    sum =0;
  }

  arr.push({data:resultArray});
  return arr;
}
```